# SFTP Connection Failing To Linode's Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, sftp, linode

I installed vsftpd on our Ubuntu machine on (Linode VPS) and followed the steps from this documentation. http://www.noob2geek.com/linux/setup-vsftpd-debian-ubuntu/

So, everything works correcly if I try to login via @root, but I cannot connect via stfp outside from server using this command.

ssh myuser@176.58.112.67

This is the terminal output: http://codepad.org/o9HaVstA

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

1. Connected as @root
2. run "nano /etc/passwd"
3. Changing user's "/bin/false"to "/bin/bash" 
   then fixed.